# run code on specific Scrollify section

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, html5-video, jquery-scrollify

I have 3 [Scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/) sections. I'm trying to play a video when you scroll to section 2 and pause it when you scroll to section 1 or 3.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/XMNzyx/)

**html**

```
data-div-name="first"

data-div-name="second"

data-div-name="third"
```

**JS**

```
before: function(first) {
    $("#video").get(0).pause();
},

before: function(second) {
    $("#video").get(0).play();
},

before: function(third) {
    $("#video").get(0).pause();
},
```

It looks like my **before functions** are overriding perhaps because I'm not **indexing** the sections properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask scrollify which section is the current and play/pause from that -

```
before: function() {
    if($.scrollify.current().hasClass('second')){
        $("#video").get(0).play();
    } else {
        $("#video").get(0).pause();
    }
},
```

Demo - http://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/KWNZXG

I don't think scrollify works the way you think with the section names, though if you want to use these data attributes you could do something like -

```
if($.scrollify.current().attr('data-div-name') === 'second'){
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a much better approach and an elegant solution :)

Comment: and you're right, I think I was using the sections improperly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

  $.scrollify({
     section:".spot",
     scrollSpeed:800,
     before: function() {

         if ($.scrollify.currentIndex() == 2){

           console.log('start');
           // Your actions...

         } else {

           console.log('end');
           // Your actions...
         }
       }
   });
```